# Windows Phone, Can you get the real time from GPS?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, gps, gps-time

Is it possible to get the real time, not system time (as this can be changed) from a GPS location request?

It seems like

```
Geoposition.Coordinate.Timestamp
```

is the system time, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.aspx

> Timestamp
>   Read-only   The system time at which the location was determined.

I know I could use NTP server but what if I don't have a data connection.

Thanks

Steve

I guess i just need a definitive answer as to whether it's possible to get the time directly from the satellite or not.

Comment: This is a tough one, you can record timestamps and then "fix them" when you get the chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm blind.

For future reference, you can in 8.1.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.aspx

see PositionSource

> PositionSourceTimestamp
>   Read-only   Gets the time at which the associated Geocoordinate position was calculated.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-geolocation-and-geofencing.aspx

From the above link:

Geolocation
In windows phone 8.0 we had two namespaces with almost identical content, the old System.Device.Location and the new Windows.Devices.Geolocation. In 8.1 only Windows.Devices.Geolocation is left. If you want to update old apps using the System.Device.Location there are plenty of information on the internet. The 8.0 maps api used System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate but 8.1 now uses Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint. More on that in my previous blog: Windows Phone 8.1 for Developers – Maps The only other changes in Windows.Devices.Geolocation are two additional classes and one extra property on Geocoordinate:

- GeoboundingBox: Represents a rectangle that defines a geographic
  area. Replaces the LocationRectangle used in the 8.0 map api
- Geopath: Represents an ordered series of geographic points and is
  used for example when you create a MapPolygon.
- **Geocoordinate.PositionSourceTimestamp: Gets the time at which the
  associated Geocoordinate position was calculated, and may be
  completely unrelated to the system time on the device. E.g. if the
  position is obtained from GPS, the timestamp would be obtained from
  the satellites.**

The final bullet point is the useful one

Thanks

Steve